# How to make the bot respond when typing in a cooldown (discord.py)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is my current code; it works, but the bot doesn't send the message:

```
@bot.on_error
async def beg_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send('This command is ratelimited, please try again in {:.2f}s'.format(error.retry_after))
    else:
        raise error

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
async def beg(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test 123")
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decorator for specific command error handler is `@command_name.error` not `@bot.on_error`

Below is the revised code:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
async def beg(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test 123")

@beg.error
async def beg_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send('This command is ratelimited, please try again in {:.2f}s'.format(error.retry_after))
    else:
        raise error
```